# PDO: make $dbh available and maintain across all php files

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, pdo

seem that I can't make it right.
Basically, three PHP files are used: - login.php, testconnect.php and numrows.php
numrows.php is the main file that first start played.

login.php and testconnect.php are good.

numrows.php:-

```
<?php
global $dbh1;
require_once "testconnect.php";

try
    {  
    $stmt = $dbh1->prepare("select count(distinct mfg_code) from test");
    $stmt->execute();
}

catch(PDOException $err)
{
    $alertmsg = $err->getMessage();
    }

$num = $stmt->fetch("PDO::FETCH_ASSOC:");
$num = json_encode($num);

echo $num;
?>
```

The log error from apache showed ""GET /testnumcards.php HTTP/1.1" 500 -".  Again the error I encountered while debugging is "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error".
What is the right way to do?

Comment: you are looking into wrong log file. You need **error_log**, not access_log

Comment: Better yet, run the php file via terminal. `user@host$ php numrows.php`

Comment: where does $alertmsg go? it seems you are plainly gag the actual error message

Comment: `$stmt->fetch("PDO::FETCH_ASSOC:")` should be `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`. Also, your `$stmt` is not accessible outside `try{}` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem not in making $dbh available but in inconsistent code and wrong syntax.
At least make your file this way, without all the useless and wrong code

```
<?php
require_once "testconnect.php";
$stmt = $dbh1->prepare("select count(distinct mfg_code) from test");
$stmt->execute();
$num = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // note the proper syntax
$num = json_encode($num);
echo $num;
```

then look into error_log for the details

Comment: Oh sigh at myself... have been looking at codes for a whole  day with no clue! Thanks!